# jQuery .load() not working in IE8

Tags: internet-explorer, jquery, internet-explorer-8

OKay, so I'm having trouble using .load in IE8. Works fine in FF, Chrome, IE9, Safari

Here's my code:

```
/* IE accessible */
var $ = jQuery.noConflict();

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("a.click").click(function (e) {
        var url = $(this).attr("href");
        e.preventDefault();
        $(".role-page #content").load(url + " .content");
    });
});
```

Heres the HTML of my nav on index.html:

```
<ul class="top-nav">
    <li><a class="click" href="inner/about.html">About Us</a></li>
    <li><a class="click" href="inner/contact.html">Contact Us</a></li>
    <li><a class="click" href="inner/test.html">Test Us</a></li>
</ul>
<section class="role-page">
    <div id="content">
        <h1>HOME PAGE BODY </h1>
    </div>
</section>
```

Is there a problem with my code? or is the problem that I'm using IE8?

Comment: What does the javascript console say? Usually if js doesn't work, there's an error that helps show why.

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using, it's quite possible that the issue is related to that.

Comment: You have a `section` tag!  That doesn't work in IE8... unless you shim it.  Have you loaded https://code.google.com/p/html5shim/?  Also, which jQuery version are you using.  2.x doesn't work in IE8, you need 1.x.

Comment: @RocketHazmat Haha, nice catch. Didn't occur me to even look at that.

Comment: @RUJordan: Not always.  Especially not in IE8 where you can get `Unspecified error` :-)

Comment: @RocketHazmat I know ;) That's why I said usually

Comment: My jquery is "<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>"

Comment: @MlgMainstream: You're welcome! :-D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using HTML5 elements on your page (`<section>`).  These don't work (natively) in IE8.  You need to shim them.

Download the HTML5shiv file and load it on your page: https://code.google.com/p/html5shim/